# Displaying Stackoverflow rating/ reputation/ badges in website

Tags: stackexchange-api

Earning reputation in Stackoverfow is a hard job, and somewhere i'll feel happy if i can get the Reputations Displayed in my website. Is it possible?

Does stackoverflow exposes any API with respect to user?

[UPDATE]

> When i simply type in
>
> http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/{user-id}/
>
> it gives me a JSON data, which seems fine to me. Is it OKAY to use it
>   like this?
>
> Got it from [stackapps.com](https://stackapps.com/questions/2704/stack-overflow-reputation-api) replied by `Nathan Osman`

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stackoverflow provides an Option to display your Reputations in your website .
we can do it via two way's(as per my knowledge):-

*Hard Way(doing everything from your own)*

- Hit the URL http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/{User-Id}/
- The above returns JSON data, which can be consumed via Ajax, and we can extract Reputations, Badges etc.
- Create your User Interface and bind the values according to your need.

*Easy Way(using Flair)*

- Go go User profile and look for hyperlink as "flair" shown below:-
  [image: Flair Option In user Profile]
- Click on it and you'll be redirected to Flair Page. Shown below:
  [image: Flair Themes]
- It gives HTML snippet, just copy and paste it where you need.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a Stackoverflow API!  V1.1 is now obsolete, so it's best to use V2.1, otherwise your code may stop working as things are deprecated.

There's a V2 example on StackApps here:

[Hello World Example](https://stackapps.com/questions/2/api-hello-world-code)

Comment: Thanks.. :) I'll go thru the details of your link, but from 1st read, it needs API key? If yes, then Is stackapps.com and Stackoverflow same ? As, if i register there(stackapps.com) will it give me my reputations from Stackoverflow?

Comment: +1 for providing me a link which has much details, i am still unaware..:)

Comment: Yeah you have to sign up to get a key, but then all the info on stack apps just relates to Stackoverflow.  It's just the site all about the Stackoverflow API so the info you get back is all about your normal rep and badges etc.